# How to find the respective terms on this problem on Partial Derivatives

Tags: partial-derivative

I was studying about partial derivatives and I got confused by this problem. 
I'm asked to prove that
$$(\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \theta})^2+ \frac{1}{r^2}(\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial r})^2=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x})^2+(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})^2$$
when I'm given that $\omega=f(x,y)$,  $x=rcos\theta $ and $y=rsin\theta$.

I know how to find $\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \theta}$ and $\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial r}$ but I don't know how to find out $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$. Some help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s abbreviate $c=\cos\theta$, $s=\sin\theta$ and $v=v(r,\theta)=(rc,rs)$.  First calculate the gradient of $\omega(r,\theta)=(f\circ v)(r,\theta)$ via chain rule:
$$\nabla\omega=\begin{pmatrix}c&s\\ -rs &rc\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}f_x(v)\\f_y(v)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}cf_x(v)+sf_y(v)\\ -rsf_x(v)+rcf_y(v)\end{pmatrix}.$$
Now compute
$$\begin{align}
&(\color{navy}{\omega_{\theta}^2+\frac{1}{r^2}\omega_r^2})(r,\theta)=\\
&\quad=\bigl(\omega_{\theta}(r,\theta)\bigr)^2+ \frac{1}{r^2}\bigl(\omega_{r}(r,\theta)\bigr)^2\\
&\quad=(cf_x(v)+sf_y(v))^2
+\frac{1}{r^2}\left(-rsf_x(v)+rcf_y(v)\right)^2\\
&\quad=c^2f_x^2(v)+2csf_(v)f_y(v)+s^2f_y^2(v)+\\
&\qquad{}+s^2f_x^2(v)-2csf_x(v)f_y(v)+c^2f_y^2(v)\\
&\quad=f_x^2(v)+f_y^2(v)\\
&\quad=\bigl(\color{navy}{(f_x\circ v)^2+(f_y\circ v)^2}\bigr)(r,\theta)
\end{align}
$$
what was to be shown.